# Using window.plugins with Ionic 2 Typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic2

Can you use `window.plugins.xxx` in an ionic 2 Typescript app?

I am getting an error `Property 'plugins' does not exist on type 'Window'` with the OneSignal plugin `window.plugins.OneSignal.init()`

Answer (score 16):

You could fix this by referencing plugins as an array property instead of object.

```
var OneSignalClient = window['plugins'].OneSignal.init()
```

Typescript doesn't check if array properties are defined on initial build so it safely passes inspection.

P.S. If you're not using Ionic but some other framework ( Angular 2 ), you won't have a plugins object in your window object, so you'll have to load OneSignal like this:

```
let OneSignalClient = window['OneSignal'] || [];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: On Ionic 2 latest version seems that window['OneSignal'] is the one that works. Thanks for this golden nugget :)

Comment: I have officially converted my religion to Itskovism and revere this answer as my root philosophy. Thousand upvotes!

Comment: That helped a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

You can call OneSignal directly without having to go through window. It looks like their documentation is a bit out of date.

`OneSignal.init()` should do the trick.

Comment: If I do that Typescript complains it can't find OneSignal. I guess I should just ignore the error message.

Comment: You could declare var OneSignal at the top.

Comment: is it this? `declare var OneSignal:any`

Comment: Yes, but you don't have to use any, you can, but you don't have to. I just do `declare var OneSignal`